# Django how to secure hidden input fields and prevent forms submitting if value changed?

Tags: python, django

I am rendering few data in hidden input. User can inspect html page and see those hidden input data. He can also change hidden input data which one kind of security risk for my website. Such as I have an hidden input where user email and name rendering like this

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="Jhone" required="">
```

User can inspect the html and change the value then my forms submitting with new updated value. is there any way to stop submitting forms if value is changed. here is my code:

**#html template**

```
{% for i in currentuser_details %}
{%for y in user_profile%}
 <input type="hidden" name='userprofile' value="{{y.id}}">
{%endfor%}        
 <input type="hidden" name="name" class="form-control"  placeholder="Your Name"  value="{{i.first_name}}" required>
<input type="hidden" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter email"value="{{ i.email }}" required>
 {%endfor%}
```

#html hidden input rendering data

```
    <input type="hidden" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="Jhone" required=""> 
 <input type="hidden" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Name" value="Jhone@gmail.com" required=""> 

   <input type="hidden" name='userprofile' value="1">
        
  <input type="hidden" name="parent" id="parent_id" value="95">
```

The most import fields for me **userprofile** and **parent**. I want to **prevent** forms submitting if any hidden value change.

**froms.py**

```
class CommentFrom(forms.ModelForm):
      captcha = CaptchaField()
      
      class Meta:
          model = BlogComment
          fields = ['name','email','comment','parent','sno','blog','user','userprofile']
```

views.py

```
if request.method == "POST":
       if comment_form.is_valid():
                isinstance = comment_form.save(commit=False)
                
                if request.user.is_authenticated:
                   isinstance.user = request.user
                elif not request.user.is_authenticated:
                   User = get_user_model()
                   isinstance.user = User.objects.get(username='anonymous_user')
                
                isinstance.blog = blog
                isinstance.save()
                messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Your Comment Pending for admin approval')
                return redirect('blog:blog-detail',slug=blog.slug)
       else:
           messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, "your comment didn't submitted. please submit again ")
                
    else:
          comment_form = CommentFrom()
```

queryset for user_profile and currentuser_details which using in views and pass the context to my html page.

`user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

`currentuser_details = UserManagement.objects.filter(username=request.user) user_profile = UserProfile.objects.filter(user=request.user)`

I think I need to be add validation in my froms.py or views.py but how to do that for hidden input and hidden foreignkey fields I don't know.

Comment: I don't know if you can directly stop a user from submitting a form if value changed using inspect, especially doing this on the client side. You can probably do it on the server side, but I guess you could try disabling inspect (although this is not recommended and does not fully work)

Comment: John Doe thanks for your comment. I need to be add validation in my froms.py or views.py but how I don't know. Wafting for an appropriate answer and hope anyone can help me on this topic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `request.session`. What i mean by this is before rendering page, you can set the values like this.

```
request.session['secret_data'] = {"key1": "value1", "key2": "value2"}
```

Then you can create a validation function that will run validation on the submitted form data and `request.session['secret_data']` values. If validation turns out to be true you can save the data else raise whatever message you want to.

```
def validate_hidden_values(request,**kwargs):
    original_data = request.session['secret_data']
    # Used **kwargs because i do not know what all the named variables you want to validate. You can get submitted data from **kwargs
    # run your validation checks
    # return True if all validation passes else return False at any point where validation fails
```

Remember to remove the `secret_data` key using `request.session.pop('secret_data')` when validation is `True`. Now removing  `secret_data` key when validation is `False` depends on your use case and you have to give a thought on that.

Comment: Amandeep Singh Sawhney Thanks for your answer. Can you pelase take any of my fields as a example and show me how to process it with session. Let pick hidden  name fields. It helps me to understand  how to implement your code properly.

Comment: Please try to give it a thought. Add some code that how you will you set `secret_data`. `secret_data` is nothing but a dictionary of your original values that you want to validate with. Read about how to raise custom exceptions. At this point of time the posted questions details are very broad. Please try to narrow it down.

Comment: Amandeep Singh Sawhney how to pass session in context and how to render it in my html ???

Comment: You already have request object in the context. In django template you can directly access `{{ request.session }}`

Comment: Amandeep Singh Sawhney In my hidden input I am trying this `<input type="hidden" name="name"  value="{{request.session.key1}}" required>` but not working. In my views.py I added ` request.session['secret_data'] = {"key1": name}`